what is the `address_labels` field in the CLI config.yml for?
In the solana cli config file (~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml) there is a address_labels array field. By default, it includes the system program.
What is this field for and where are the labels displayed within the toolsuite?
I thought maybe within solana logs so I tried adding some usual programs and doing some testing, but no thing.

It's really not used often. From a search through the source code, it's only used with format_labeled_address https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/990f938a718d4bcc791e26002a5475a233afa4c8/cli-output/src/display.rs#L126
This function is only used in the CLI for tagging validator addresses, ie https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/d9683093ec5ce3138ab94332e248c524a2e60454/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L1312
Here's another usage in watchtower, also for tagging validators: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/d9683093ec5ce3138ab94332e248c524a2e60454/watchtower/src/main.rs#L328

yeah, looks to be. I wonder if it could be used in more ways and be more useful in the cli?

We could make use of it anytime a pubkey is printed, so maybe loads of places!
